# Rating System PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I followed this tutorial: http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/rating_script.htm

but when i run it i get

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mode in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\index.php on line 7.
```

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: what is in line 7 can you show the line no 7?

Comment: you are going to need to post the code

Comment: "*Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong?*" - On line 7 of your file `C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\index.php`, you are referring to a variable `mode` which has not been defined.

Comment: That code is pretty sloppy and outdated. It makes little to no sense. I would suggest not using it. Mode is not even defined also it should be `$mode` and not mode. It uses outdated techniques such as `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, a security risk in its own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are copying their script exactly, the issue is found on step 3 - http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/rating_script_3.htm

```
//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
if ( $mode=="vote")
```

You are checking an undefined variable - `$mode`. You need to define it first, with something like -

```
//We only run this code if the user has just clicked a voting link
$mode = isset($_GET['mode']) ? htmlentities($_GET['mode']) : '';
if ( $mode=="vote")
```

Note: I agree `@azizpunjani`, this code is outdated, and has many issues. You should look for a script that is using `mysqli_` or `PDO`, not `mysql_` functions.

Comment: Thanks now i'm getting error "Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\index.php on line 59" my line 59 is as follows: $current = $row['RatingTotal'] / $row['Rating'];

Comment: You need to check if there are more than `0` votes (or `rating`, according to your code). Try changing it to - `$current = ($row['Rating'] == 0) ? 0 : $row['RatingTotal'] / $row['Rating'];`. If no votes/ratings have been submitted yet, ie. `$row['Rating'] == 0`, `$current` will be `0`, but will be `$row['RatingTotal'] / $row['Rating']` if `$row['Rating'] >= 1`